# How to check if a facebook account exists?

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to check if a Facebook user with the username "abc.def" exists.

```
echo file_get_contents("https://www.facebook.com/abc.def");
```

My plan is to use PHP DOM library to read the text on the page.

Instead of redirecting to the user profile, it opens a page that says select your browser.

Please advise.

Comment: `file_get_contents()` is not the tool for this job. You will need to use cURL so that you can control headers, cookies and the rest. Specifically, for this you will need to add a User-Agent string to your request, but expect Facebook to put other hurdles in your way.

Comment: This kind of scraping is against Facebook’s ToS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requirements:

- Create a Google Search Engine: https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/cse
- Create Google API Key: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview
  You must create those 2 in order to use the following code. Also in your search engine you should create one that would only search on Facebook or if latter you want to do for instagram as well, just create another search engine that would only search on instagram. You can create that on the first website I sent.

```
<?php


    $mySearchEngine = '----';//https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/cse/all
    $myGoogleApiKey = '----';//https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

    //$queryExactTerm = 'If you want to use exact name';
    //$queryExactUrl = urlencode($queryExactTerm);

    $query = 'Name Of the person you want to search';
    $queryUrl = urlencode($query);
    
    
    $pg = 1;//If you do not find the name you want, you can loop and go to next pages, by changing this to 11,21,31...101
    
    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?';
    $url .= 'key='.$myGoogleApiKey;
    $url .= '&cx='.$mySearchEngine;
    $url .= '&q='.$queryUrl;
    $url .= '&start='.$pg;
    //$url .= '&exactTerms='.$queryExactUrl;
            

    $responseJson = curl_no_proxy($url);
    $responseArr = json_decode($responseJson, TRUE);
    
    if(isset($responseArr['items'])){
        foreach($responseArr['items'] as $key => $value){
            echo '<hr>';
            $title = $value['htmlTitle'];
            $link = $value['link'];
            
            echo $title.'<br>';
            echo $link.'<br>';

            //print_r($value);
            //You can get all information you want from here
        }
       
       
    }
   
    //If you want to see all the results 
    //foreach($responseArr as $key => $value){
        //echo '<hr>';
        //echo $key.'<br>';
        //print_r($value);
    //}
    
    function curl_no_proxy($url){
        $ch = CURL_INIT();
        CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
        CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,True);
        CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,True);
        CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
        CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,30);
        CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30); 
        $result = CURL_EXEC($ch);
        CURL_CLOSE($ch);
        return $result;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tM9q.jpg)The code below works for me. But I believe that after doing this action a lot of time Facebook will probably block your ip. So I suggest you use some proxies to make your system working better and without stopping.
One more thing, I really suggest you test the proxies by yourself because It would be easier to find one that works.

```
$url = 'https://www.facebook.com/profileName/';
$ch = CURL_INIT();
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0');
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE,CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,True);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,True);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,30);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30); 
echo $result = CURL_EXEC($ch);
```

If you need to use proxy, You can use like this:

```
$ip = '185.18.212.227';
$port = '3128';
$proxy = $ip.':'.$port;
/**
* If your proxy Require user or password
*/
$user = '';
$pwd ='';
$credential = $user.':'.$pwd;
$url = 'https://www.facebook.com/profileName/';
$ch = CURL_INIT();
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $ip);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $port);
//CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);//This one also can be used instead of the 2 lines above
//CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $credential); In case of password is required to access
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0');
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE,CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,True);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,True);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,30);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30); 
echo $result = CURL_EXEC($ch);
```

[image]

---

The next part will be divided into basically 5 Parts:
1- I will Get all the free proxies in the first page of the https://free-proxy-list.net/
2- Save those proxies in an array with keys being the proxyIp and values as the proxyPorts
3- Check if those proxies are really working by scraping data from google.com, if it is working we would get something, If not working we would get nothing
4-Save the proxies that are working in order to use them to test if Facebook already block or not those IPs like they probably did to yours
5- Use to curl Facebook.

Just remember, what I am doing will take some time because I am opening like 30 to 40 proxies to open one page. So I suggest that you have a CronJob doing the part of getting proxies from multiple websites for free, and testing them to see if they work, and you would just be using them to scrape data that would be the optimum method I believe.
Also To use the next script you need to have simple_html_dom, you can get here: https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io
I am using it just to collect the proxies I am using.

```
ini_set("memory_limit",-1);
ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', 0);

include 'simple_html_dom.php';


$goodProxy = array();

//1- Get all the free proxies in the first page of the https://free-proxy-list.net/
$url = 'https://free-proxy-list.net/';

$ch = CURL_INIT();
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,True);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,30);
CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30); 
$result = CURL_EXEC($ch);

$html =  new simple_html_dom();
$html ->load($result);
$table = $html->find('table',0);
$line = $table->find('tbody',0)->find('tr');

$ipProxyPorts = array();

foreach($line as $keys => $value){
    $ip = $value->find('td',0)->plaintext;
    $port = $value->find('td',1)->plaintext;
    $ipProxyPorts[$ip] = $port;
}
print_r($ipProxyPorts);
echo '<br><br><br><br><br><br>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<br><br><br><br><br><br>';
//2- Got all the ips in the first page and they are set inside an array :$ipProxyPorts has the keys as the ip and the values as the ports 

//3- Next we will just check if those proxies are correct or if they can be used or not by scraping the first page of Google
//This part might take some time that is why it is important you set memory limit and max executing time to infinite on the top of the page
foreach($ipProxyPorts as $ip => $port){
    $url = 'https://www.google.com';
    $ch = CURL_INIT();
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $ip);
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $port);
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0');
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE,CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,True);
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,True);
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,30);
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30); 
    
    echo $result = CURL_EXEC($ch);

    $textString = strip_tags($result);
    if(strlen($textString) > 20){
        $goodProxy[$ip] = $port;
    }
    
    curl_close($ch);
    echo '<hr>';
}

//4- Here are the proxies that are working right now and you could try to see if facebook already blocked them or not, but at least one of them must be ok to use I believe
echo ' "Proxy:port" that are working right now from the website https://free-proxy-list.net/';
print_r($goodProxy);

//5- Now you can use those proxies to see which one would not be blocked by facebook

foreach($goodProxy as $ip => $port){
    echo 'Proxy Used:'.$ip.':'.$port;
    $url = 'https://www.facebook.com/hygison/';
    $ch = CURL_INIT();
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $ip);
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $port);
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0');
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE,CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,True);
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,True);
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,30);
    CURL_SETOPT($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30); 
    echo $result = CURL_EXEC($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo '<hr>';
}
```

Comment: Are you changing the link : `$url = 'https://www.facebook.com/profileName/';` for the profile name you are looking for? If the profileName is wrong it will give you the login page, but if it is write it will give you the user profile. Try with my account:  `$url = 'https://www.facebook.com/hygison/';`

Comment: Yes, I did. It still does not work. Could this be the operating system or PHP version?

Comment: I am using php 8.0.0 with Mama and Apache. I just checked that code in my Xampp as well in a Windows server and it also worked. And there I am using 8.0.3. What about you, which version are you using? If you are using the same version as me, I believe you have tried already to scrape Facebook so much that they blocked your IP. So you should use the second code I wrote there.

Comment: I have added 2 pictures, one using an existent name for the profile(my name) and another one using some name that would not exist.In the first case you could automatically find if the profile you wrote exists or not.

Comment: I still see the login screen with either code. I tried using a VPN as well. My PHP Version is 7.4.2. I am using MAMP on Mac. I tested on a couple of profiles including my own. Still no luck. Please advise.

Comment: I believe the problem is not the php version, but your IP. Because we are both able to curl Facebook, the difference is that Facebook is redirecting you to the login page and in my case they are letting me see the user page. So I will add a script to get proxies from a website https://free-proxy-list.net and then test those proxies to see which one is working, and lest use those tips to check which one I can use to curl Facebook. Sounds good for you?

Comment: You can also google Google API in order to do collect the data you want, actually just to check if the user exist or not. If you want that, let me know and I would show how to do by using Google Search engine : https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/cse/all

Comment: Yes, I agree. The problem is with the IP address. Man, you are a genius!! How can we use Google Search Engine in this case? Very interesting!!

Comment: FYI the above code proxy code doesn't work either. It looks like this is more to do with my ISP. Can you please guide me in the other direction where we can query Google. I got the hint but still not clear about the approach.

Comment: Sure, I will prepare another answer =)

Comment: Thank you very much! Looking forward to it

Comment: Done, you can take a look there now =)